# Is it possible to upload a file to a website using a batch file?

Tags: file, batch-file, upload

As the title says, is it possible to upload a file to a website using a batch file??

Comment: You should at least search before you ask such a broad question.

Comment: Does it have FTP server there? Is there any kind of  service that can handle POST requests? Do you have any OS credentials?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can for instance use wput, http://wput.sourceforge.net/